# Understanding fromhex() function in python

Tags: python-3.x, hexdump

In this python pgm, I am converting string to hexadecimal

```
s ='0200'
print(bytes.fromhex(s))
```

According to my understanding, ASCII value of each character
0 - 48
2 - 50
0 - 48
0 - 48

On converting 48 50 48 48 to hexadecimal we get
\x30\x32\x30\x30

But what I actually got is : b'\x02\x00'.

The output I got behaved like as if Binary Coded decimal (0200) input was provided.

Can any one help me under this behavior

Comment: Why do you assume the ASCII value of the characters is relevant? ``'0200'`` is already representing a literal hexadecimal number – with the digits 0, 2, 0, 0.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi S='0200' is a string. If I type(s) I get string as type

Comment: So? It's a string *of the hexadecimal digits 0, 2, 0, 0*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Can you please provide any article to clear my doubts on it

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what your doubts are before I can clear them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My understanding was whatever presented in '' is string.